# Is $a^x \pmod{n} = (a\pmod{n})^{x \pmod{n}}$?

Tags: solution-verification, modular-arithmetic, modules, exponentiation, calculator

Is it right to claim that:

$a^x \pmod{n} = (a \pmod{n})^{x \pmod{n}}$?

I know that:

$a^x \pmod{n} = (a \pmod{n})^{x}$?

Comment: Welcome to math.stackexchange! It is generally frowned upon to ask questions without including background information, including in particular what you've tried yourself. What have you tried? Are you confused by any of the notation in the question? Do you have a working definition of what $a\pmod{n}$ means, and when you can say that $a\pmod{n} = b\pmod{n}$ (usually written $a\equiv b\pmod{n}$)? Have you tried any concrete examples to see if this holds in those cases?

Answer (score 2):

Not necessarily. Note that

$$a^{x \text{ mod }n} \text{mod }n \equiv a^x \text{mod } n$$ implies that

$$a^n \text{ mod n}\equiv 1$$,

which by [Fermat's Little Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem) is wrong in infinitely many cases, as if n is prime,

$$a^n \text{ mod n} \equiv a^{n-1}$$ which is almost never true. An example of this is $a=2,n=7,x=8$, resulting in

$$2 \text{ mod 7} \equiv 2^8 \text{ mod 7}\equiv 4$$

Which clearly isn't true

Answer (score 0):

It is not true in general. Consider the following example:

$3^3 (mod\;5) = 2$ and $(3^3)^6 (mod\;5) \neq 2^1$

Answer (score 0):

No, and this is an interesting twist in modular arithmetic!

You can see for yourself that the answer is No, with a simple example, such as $$ 2 ^ 3 \bmod 3 = 2 \ne 1 = ( 2 \bmod 3 ) ^ { 3 \bmod 3 } $$ or the examples in the other answers.  But more interesting is to see what *is* true instead.

Modular arithmetic works because $ a + b \equiv c + d \pmod n $ and $ a b \equiv c d \pmod n $ whenever $ a \equiv c \pmod n $ and $ b \equiv d \pmod n $.  As the examples show, we *don't* get $ a ^ b \equiv c ^ d \pmod n $ when $ a \equiv c \pmod n $ and $ b \equiv d \pmod n $.  However, we *do* get $ a ^ b \equiv c ^ d \pmod n $ when $ a \equiv c \pmod n $ and $ b \equiv d \pmod { \lambda ( n ) } $, where $ \lambda $ is the [Carmichael function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carmichael_function), whenever $ b $ and $ d $ are sufficiently large (specifically, whenever they're both at least as big as the largest exponent on a prime number in the prime factorization of $ n $).  So the lesson is, exponents must be reduced modulo $ \lambda ( n ) $ instead of modulo $ n $ like everything else.  (And annoyingly, you have to check that this reduced exponent is large enough.)

For example, since $ \lambda ( 3 ) = 2 $, we might get $$ 2 ^ 3 \bmod 3 = ( 2 \bmod 3 ) ^ { 3 \bmod 2 } \text . $$  I say that we *might* get this, since we still need to check that both exponents, $ 3 $ and $ 3 \bmod 2 $, are sufficiently large.  Since $ 3 = 3 ^ 1 $ has $ 1 $ as the highest exponent in its prime factorization, and since both $ 3 $ and $ 3 \bmod 2 = 1 $ are at least as large as $ 1 $, we're good.  (And I really only needed to check $ 3 \bmod 2 = 1 $, since the unreduced exponent $ 3 $ can only be even larger.)  And you can see if you check that this equation is true.

For a more complicated example, what is $ { 5 1 } ^ { 7 3 } \bmod 1 8 $?  Well, you have to calculate $ \lambda ( 1 8 ) $, but that's not too bad.  You can see how to calculate it in the Wikipedia article that I linked above, and the answer is $ 6 $.  So reduce $ 5 1 $ modulo $ 1 8 $ to $ 1 5 $, and reduce $ 7 3 $ modulo $ 6 $ to $ 1 $.  So hopefully, we can just take $ 1 5 ^ 1 = 1 5 $.  But wait!  We also need to check that the exponents are sufficiently large.  Since $ 1 8 = 2 ^ 1 \cdot 3 ^ 2 $, the largest exponent in the prime factorization is $ 2 $, so we need $ 7 3 \bmod 6 $ be at least $ 2 $, which it's not.  But don't despair!  We'll just lower $ 7 3 $ below a multiple of $ 6 $ to get $ 7 1 \bmod 6 = 5 $, which is large enough.  Then write $ 5 1 ^ { 7 3 } = 5 1 ^ { 7 1 } \cdot 5 1 ^ 2 $.  For $ 5 1 ^ { 7 1 } $, we reduce $ 5 1 $ modulo $ 1 8 $ to $ 1 5 $ as before, and reduce $ 7 1 $ modulo $ 6 $ to $ 5 $; since $ 5 \geq 2 $ (the largest exponent in the prime factorization of $ 1 8 $), we're allowed to say that $ 5 1 ^ { 7 1 } \equiv 1 5 ^ 5 \pmod { 1 8 } $.  And since $ 1 5 \equiv - 3 \pmod { 1 8 } $, we can even change this to $ ( - 3 ) ^ 5 = - 2 4 3 \equiv 9 \pmod { 1 8 } $.  (But it's also not too hard to start with $ 1 5 $ as long as you reduce mod $ 1 8 $ at each step.)  For $ 5 1 ^ 2 $, we can still reduce $ 5 1 $ mod $ 1 8 $ to $ 1 5 $, and then $ 1 5 ^ 2 = 2 2 5 \equiv 9 \pmod { 1 8 } $.  Multiplying these together, we get $ 9 \cdot 9 = 8 1 \equiv 9 \pmod { 1 8 } $.  Therefore, $ 5 1 ^ { 7 3 } \bmod 1 8 $ is $ 9 $.